# Allow SmithHtmlEditor for Spell Check

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, spell-checking, html-editor

I'm using the SmithHtmlEditor and it is working fine but we've had the request to add spell checking that is native to WPF `<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled=True />`  I've simply tried adding that line to the TextBox in the control but I'm not getting the squiggly line and the context menu with suggestions, maybe b/c the WindowsFormsHost.  I'm open to changing controls as well.

```
            <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="CodeEditor"
                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                     AcceptsTab="True"
                     AutoWordSelection="True"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"/>
            <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="BrowserHost">
                <wf:WebBrowser x:Name="VisualEditor" />
            </WindowsFormsHost>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: your code is enabling spellcheck on the TextBox, NOT WindowsFormsHost.  is that intended?

Answer (score 1):

This enables spell check to the text editor only. If you go to **code mode** you will see that spell check is enabled there but only there.
The WebBrowser is WinForms component and you can't add spellcheck in that way.